# Nuxt.js- share link of a persisted data: how the receiver can view the data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt/vuetify application, I have a set of actions/steps the user should fulfill through the user interface. At each step, asynchronous requests are made to fetch data which then is saved in `store/index.js`.

The steps and subsequent choices are used to construct the URL path for each situation/click.

I used a plugin to persist the data so that the user can click on the back and forward by clicking on the browser arrow symbols (history) and see the previous steps with data persisted and thus displayed.

Now I am thinking of the situation where the user shares the link of any step he achieved (meaning he landed on a page after a series of steps and the data he selected is displayed): if he shares the link with someone else on the Internet, the receiver of the link will not see any data displayed because I used `store/index.js` to store it and a plugin to persist Nuxt state.

**Question**: What approaches/alternatives are there to achieve my goal? I want to allow the user to share the link of the last step he fulfilled and the receiver of his link should view the data the sender selected.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the data via query strings in the url. For example, make the url like this:

`https://example.com/form/?answer1=3&answer2=4&answer3=blah`

This will make the form stateless, and immune to refreshes. If the user shares the link, you can see what answers have been chosen already by which ones are present in the query string and display the appropriate form to continue choosing.

Note: In Vue js with vue-router, query strings can be accessed like this: `this.$route.query['querystringkey']`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. But for the moment, I have not implemented the backend, my links are in the form `http:3000/choices/1/subChoice/2`. I simulate the shared link by opening the same link on a different browser where I can not see the data.